# "BOOTMANAGER is missing" when optical drive connected

Tags: windows-10, optical-drive, bootmgr

My computer fails to boot from SSD when optical drive is connected. It has worked perfectly for something like a year without it and now I have the same issue again when trying to connect it with another SATA cable that I ordered.

I have disabled the DVD drive from all boot settings and added the SSD as first everywhere but it does not help. There is also a boot override option that allows me to forcibly boot from the SSD but same result. I have also tried fiddling with the fast boot settings and other stuff under the boot menu in bios but nothing has an impact. The optical drive is also empty (no CD/DVD) if you are wondering.

Any idea what I could do? I have Hirens boot CD on USB and I will happily use it if needed. The Mobo is a workstation version that I bought ~4 years ago and I believe the optical drive is 6 years old and connects with SATA.

Could it be that my workstation Mobo with integrated mini-ssd for faster boot is causing trouble? Or could it be the optical drive being too old? Any help is appreciated, haven't been able to find anyone with the exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i managed to "fix" this myself i think. I had to enable UEFI boot only and now everything works like a charm.

Comment: If you're user Joakim, thanks for closing the loop on your question.  If you repost this under your original username, you will be able to accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark next to it, which will indicate that the problem has been solved.  In general, you'll want to use a single user account because that enables you to edit your own posts, comment within your thread, and accept answers.  This [link](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) will guide you to getting your accounts merged.

Comment: Yeah i just had some odd issues with my first account and was in a hurry. How do i merge the accounts if one is (unregistered)? It asks for email and i don't think there is one connected.

Comment: I think you need an email account to associate with a SU account, and both of these are registered accounts.  But if one account is unregistered or the two were created with different email addresses, the system manages to deal with it.  Just give it a shot and see what happens.  As long as the system administrators have a way to contact you, they can figure it out.